# Laravel Email Confirmation On Registration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-authorization

I need to send an email after a new user is created.

But I don't know how to return to the home page without getting an error.
This is what I am doing right now.

```
User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'phone' => bcrypt($data['phone']),
            'confirmation_code' => str_random(30),
        ]);

Email_function();

if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $data['email'], 'password' => bcrypt($data['password']) ])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

I keep getting this as my error message.

```
SErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 439:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, null given, called in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/sniddl/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 63 and defined
```

**Edit:**
changed the title to reflect the answer.

Comment: Where's the rest of the error?

Comment: I added it now. Sorry about that.

Comment: Which is line 63 of RegistersUser?  The auth::attempt?

Comment: RegisterUser is a default file.
here is the line though
`Auth::guard($this->getGuard())->login($this->create($request->all()));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a modified create function with an added email function for your register controller

Make sure Request is included in the pages top with namespaces being used:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Change the create function in your controller:

```
protected function create(Request $data)
{


    $user                       = new User;
    $user->name                 = $data->input('name');
    $user->username             = $data->input('username');
    $user->email                = $data->input('email');
    $user->password             = bcrypt($data->input('password'));
    $user->phone                = bcrypt($data->input('phone'));
    $user->confirmation_code    = str_random(60);
    $user->save();

    if ($user->save()) {

        $this->sendEmail($user);

        return redirect('VIEWPATH.VIEWFILE')->with('status', 'Successfully created user.');

    } else {

        return redirect('VIEWPATH.VIEWFILE')->with('status', 'User not created.');

    }

}
```

Create the sendEmail function in the same controller that will use Laravels built in email. Make sure you create and your HTML email:

```
public function sendEmail(User $user)
{
    $data = array(
        'name' => $user->name,
        'code' => $user->confirmation_code,
    );
    \Mail::queue('EMAILVIEWPATH.HTMLEMAILVIEWFILE', $data, function($message) use ($user) {
        $message->subject( 'Subject line Here' );
        $message->to($user->email);
    });
}
```

NOTE:
Your going to need to update the `VIEWPATH.VIEWFILE` and `EMAILVIEWPATH.HTMLEMAILVIEWFILE` at a minimium in the examples above.

Check the repos below for CONTROLLER :
https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php
https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthController.php

REGISTER VIEW(blade) EXAMPLE
https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/resources/views/auth/register.blade.php

EMAIL VIEW THAT RECEIVES VARIABLES:
https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-auth/blob/master/resources/views/emails/activateAccount.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out, by setting `User::create` as a variable it allows you to login in the user by returning the variable. Like this.

```
$user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'phone' => bcrypt($data['phone']),
            'confirmation_code' => str_random(30),
        ]);

Email_function();

return $user;
```

Comment: It this how you are creating a user in your auth controller?